# How to resolve 'Request header is too large' error in Spring Boot 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am getting the following error when doing a simple GET request to an endpoint. After running the app I just hit `http://localhost:8080/api/user`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:790)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeader(Http11InputBuffer.java:975)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:604)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:295)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The embedded tomcat core version is `10.1.1` and java version is `17`.

I know we can specify the max header size in `server.max-http-header-size` inside application properties but in Spring Boot 3.0.0 that are deprecated and will be removed soon. So, I don't want to use that for resolving this issue.

If anybody knows how to solve this issue in latest release if spring boot (3.x.x) that would be a great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be careful trying to do this too much.  Tomcat already has a pretty generous header size but if you were to use some other server in front of Tomcat (i.e. Apache, Nginx, etc) it may have something different.  Are you really trying to put ~8k of data into the header?  These restrictions were put in place to reduce denial of service attacks.  How big do you need?

Comment: In case you still want to use the property. I think `server.max-http-header-size` is deprecated in favor of `server.max-http-request-header-size` in Spring Boot 3.0.0